# Guacamole internal error

Tags: linux, tomcat7, remote-desktop, guacamole

So I followed a bunch of tutorials and installed tomcat7 and guacamole (http://guac-dev.org/) on an ubuntu server (virtual machine).

I managed to set everything up...tomcat is running perfectly.
But whenever I try to connect via *localhost:8080/guacamole/* and log in..I get this error saying:

*Internal error...* with a countdown that reloads the page

I used guacd -f to and found out that apparently it is "*Unable to bind socket to any addresses.*"

Looking at the manual (http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/troubleshooting.html) I found this error and followed the instructions on how to fix it and changed the port information.
Didn't work! And I didn't find anything after hours of google searches.

Do you have an idea what I can do?

Comment: have you checked whether some other process is lestening on this port? you can use, for example, netstats for this. Also, what ports did you try to bind?

Comment: Yes - And even though 4820 is free, I changed it to 4822, 4830 and 22222.

Also changed it in the preference file - didn't work.

Comment: could you show more logs? at least several lines before. and also, can you bind some other app to these ports? e.g. some debug server